# How should I register my users without email address?

Tags: joomla-3.x, registration

I'd like to bulk register users without email address in my component. Afaik there isn't a database constraint, so in theory it is possible to inject the rows necessary to do this. I'd rather use the JUser class if it is possible to do the same with that. What I need from it is password hashing and username generation from the real name. Any experience with that?

Comment: try this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34921238/3114661

Comment: @Joomler What happens with your code when you pass an empty email? ...

Comment: email is required, if email is empty then it wont add the user.

Comment: @Joomler Ye, that's the problem this question is about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution for password encryption: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304038/joomla-3-2-1-password-encryption

```
jimport('joomla.user.helper');
$yourpass = JUserHelper::hashPassword($password_choose);
```

So I just hash the password and insert the row to the `users` table with empty email. Adding them to some groups is just as easy by adding rows to the `user_usergroup_map` table. If you want the users to be able to login, you need to add them at least to the registered user group. I generated a dummy email address too, something like `{username}.dummy@host` just to be sure, but this solution does not send out annoying registration emails.

Comment: I think you are a better off to insert a dummy email for each user lest you keep hitting email required warnings if you ever try to edit the user in the backend for example. Something like: random_string_here@yourowndomain.com and as long as your domain's catchall is configured to discard all email then that should be fine.

Comment: @jamesgarrett Thanks James! Email is not important in this scenario. I just need around 150 users to be able to login and use a relative simple component.

Comment: @jamesgarrett Should I add a formally valid email, like `{username}@xxx.com` to avoid errors?

Comment: i don't think it matters if the email account exists or not if that is what you are asking.  So {username}@xxx.com or dkf93tkos0ekfku3@xxx.com are both suitable dummy email addresses to use.  I should add to be clear, if it is not obvious, that I suggesting that you generate a unique random string for each user.

Comment: @jamesgarrett I thought I just leave it empty, but okay adding a non-existent email address of the same domain cannot hurt. Is there a way to reuse the text -> dash/underscore case transformation in joomla? For example it is used by converting article titles to uris.

Comment: You mean JFilterOutput::stringURLSafe($string) ?

Comment: @jamesgarrett Probably. Thanks, I'll try it out, but I checked again the feature, and it strips accented letters like éáőú etc. instead of using the non accented version eaou. It might be not as good as I thought. https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/6e07ca6fadd8a5d1db3337cf0357d782646f5411/libraries/joomla/filter/output.php

Comment: The transliteration method depends on the current language you have set - so I presume the english language packs don't handle the accent transliterations like they probably should.  I haven't looked into it so maybe it's something else.

Comment: @jamesgarrett Ohh okay. Then I just have to set the language properly. Thanks!